# How to get specific data out of an API using the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

This is probably an easy fix however I'm unable to see the solution. My project that I've been taking way too much time on is finally starting to close up, however I'm towards the very end and I'm having problems with the API I'm working with.

I'm expecting that whenever I use my match in `HeroDetail`, I will be able to use that ID to locate the hero's who data I want to display whenever you click on it. My other components work exactly how I believe they should. They route me to my `HeroDetail` page with an ID that is specific to a hero I click on.

The problem I'm having is, with this API, I do not know how to use that ID to pull the `heroStats` for that specific ID out.

I thought I might be able to add a little params at the end of the URL like `?_id=${}` but that was unsuccessful. The API URL is https://docs.opendota.com/#section/Introduction if you want to read a little on it as well. I haven't been able to find anything that can help me.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./App.css";


function HeroDetail({match}) {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchHero();
        console.log(match)
    },[]);

    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

    const fetchHero = async () => {
        const fetchHero = await fetch(`https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats}`);
        const item = await fetchHero.json();
        setItem(item);
        console.log(item)
    };
    return(
        <div>
           <h1>{item.id} </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HeroDetail;
```

Comment: Can you try `const hero = item.find(h => h.id === /* the id of the hero you want */)`

Comment: const hero = item.find(h => h.id === match.params.id) gives me undefined

Comment: Is there a hero with the id `match.params.id` in the data you get from the `fetch()`?

Comment: No I have a list and it's dynamically created. Say I select the 4 hero, then my url will be `http://localhost:3000/select/4` and I'm trying to use that 4 to find the hero in heroStats, using the API

Comment: If you have copy pasted the above code snippet from your production code, it might be worth noting that there is a trailing '}' in your fetch URL

Comment: @Nitin that was corrected sorry

Comment: Tim's approach should give you the proper hero. Could you confirm that the type of `match.params.id` is indeed a Number and not a string?

Comment: Hey @4156, I've added a link to a codesandbox in an answer with a working example for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw together a small CodeSandBox that has a working example of what I was talking about in the OP comments.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-leftpad-cbjb3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `const heroId = match.params.id;
        const hero = item.find(element => element.id === heroId);
        console.log(hero);` still gives me undefined

Comment: Is `match.params.id` undefined?

Comment: No, I have another component that maps all the heroes and the key is their id, once I click on the hero I want to choose it adds that ID to the url and that's what match.params.id returns. So in this case I selected Bloodseeker and 4 was returned

Comment: https://github.com/kevin6767/api_search If you want to check everything out

Comment: There's no package.json?

Comment: I just added it my fault

Comment: Unrelated, but considering you already fetch that api route in the parent component, you may as well pass the data around instead of re-fetching

Comment: Ah, simple fix, `heroId` needs to be of type `Number`
`const hero = item.find(element => element.id === Number(heroId));`

Comment: Also don't forget to update `hero/setItem` after `.find`ing the hero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208891/discussion-between-4156-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

Opendota doesn't provide API for retrieving HeroStat by id. But you can fetch the HeroStats only once. Store them into your store(if you are using Redux). Use `filter` of `find` to get the exact heroStat with your id. Furthermore, you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create memoized selectors.

Answer (score -1):

As the API document, we can see that it will give a array of object.

[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "localized_name": "string",
    "img": "string",
    "icon": "string",
    "pro_win": 0,
    "pro_pick": 0,
    "hero_id": 0,
    "pro_ban": 0,
    "1_pick": 0,
    "1_win": 0,
    "2_pick": 0,
    "2_win": 0,
    "3_pick": 0,
    "3_win": 0,
    "4_pick": 0,
    "4_win": 0,
    "5_pick": 0,
    "5_win": 0,
    "6_pick": 0,
    "6_win": 0,
    "7_pick": 0,
    "7_win": 0
  }
]

So, if you want to access the id then in your case,
item[0].id will work, or you can use find

const found = item.find(element => element.id == 'whatever id');

console.log(found);